# Java - Premature EOF - Better Way to write web reader?

Tags: java, eclipse, eof

I have this code that I use to read a source code of a webpage . This code is in loop and it runs for many many times . However it doesn't finish it most of the times . For example if the output file should be 180kb text file , I have 180 which means It is complete and I also get all sorts of sizes like 9kb,150kb,170kb,50kb,etc ... What I mean is for every 10 loop it give me a complete page 3 times out of 10 and around 7 times incomplete source file .

```
URL site = null;
site = new URL("http://www.someurl/page/"+ i);
URLConnection yc = null;
yc = site.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = null;
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;
System.out.println("Page Starts : " + i  );

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(inputLine);

    }

    in.close();
```

I have read somewhere about premature EOF That data is coming slower than it is being processed , I like to point out I have slow connection and I run this same code on my win7-64 and it gave me 3 out of 10 complete . I run through eclipse in virtual windows xp with less memory and processing power and it gives me way better around 6 out of 10 complete but still gives me error .

I have used throws IOException and it gives me this error and stops the code :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at SourceCodeExtractor.main(SourceCodeExtractor.java:34)
```

I have removed throws and use try catch it continue with next file with complete last loop or incomplete ( I get my source code , it may be 180kb or 9kb ) . I said to spit out error 2 when tries the while loop and it does so I can say it is the problem with while ...

Comment: are the websites you are connecting to are slow too?

Comment: not really they are decent . anyway I have 28kb download speed but the code uses less than 5kbps bandwidth . I am also open to other suggestions . fell free to present whole new code ... I am not bound to this code but its the only way I know to read the web .

Comment: can you paste the whole code with the real website names you are using? I would like to try it on my side.

Comment: For the website I can't since its for my work project . However Here is anandtech that uses the same format . U won't get the exact error when you run it but it still gives me incomplete pages(less but they are there ) for the reasons I can't figure out . Full Code : http://pastebin.com/pNqiRmPy

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that your code goes a lot faster if you get rid of this line:

```
System.out.println(inputLine);
```

Comment: Yes.  But you will get faster downloads / fewer exceptions if you don't waste time writing each line to the console

Comment: doesn't matter . when I actually use the code I use it to write source code to file . I just use system.out.println"pagenum"+i and even without filewriter and print to console still get the same error frequently. The code already partly works . I like to know how to fix it .